# How can i use single css file in "Combinator" css compression plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, css, cakephp

Hi iam using "Combinator" its a plugin for compressing js and css .
[Combinator link and steps](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/st3ph/2010/09/10/combinator-compress-and-combine-your-js-and-css-files)

According to the docs 
they said add following line to views or layout

```
<?php $combinator->add_libs('js', array('jquery'));?> 
<?php $combinator->add_libs('css', array('styles'));?>
```

but how do i add single css file instead of these entire css ?

helper class code:

```
    <?php  
class CombinatorHelper extends Helper { 
    var $Vue = null; 
    var $libs = array('js' => array(), 'css' => array()); 
    var $inline_code = array('js' => array(), 'css' => array()); 
    var $basePath = null; 
    var $cachePath = null; 

    // default conf 
    private $__options = array( 
                            'js' => array( 
                                'path' => '/js', 
                                'cachePath' => '/js', 
                                'enableCompression' => true 
                            ), 
                            'css' => array( 
                                'path' => '/css', 
                                'cachePath' => '/css', 
                                'enableCompression' => false, 
                                'compression' => 'high_compression' // Can be "high_compression", "highest_compression", "low_compression", or "default"
                            ) 
                        ); 

    function __construct($options = array()) { 
        $this->__options['js'] = !empty($options['js'])?am($this->__options['js'], $options['js']):$this->__options['js']; 
        $this->__options['css'] = !empty($options['css'])?am($this->__options['css'], $options['css']):$this->__options['css']; 
        $this->Vue =& ClassRegistry::getObject('view'); 

        $this->__options['js']['path'] = $this->clean_path($this->__options['js']['path']); 
        $this->__options['js']['cachePath'] = $this->clean_path($this->__options['js']['cachePath']); 
        $this->__options['css']['path'] = $this->clean_path($this->__options['css']['path']); 
        $this->__options['css']['cachePath'] = $this->clean_path($this->__options['css']['cachePath']); 

        $this->basePath['js'] = WWW_ROOT.$this->__options['js']['path']; 
        $this->cachePath['js'] = WWW_ROOT.$this->__options['js']['cachePath']; 
        $this->basePath['css'] = WWW_ROOT.$this->__options['css']['path']; 
        $this->cachePath['css'] = WWW_ROOT.$this->__options['css']['cachePath']; 
    } 

    function scripts($type) { 
        switch($type) { 
            case 'js': 
                $cachefile_js = $this->generate_filename('js'); 
                return $this->get_js_html($cachefile_js); 
            case 'css': 
                $cachefile_css = $this->generate_filename('css'); 
                return $this->get_css_html($cachefile_css); 
            default: 
                $cachefile_js = $this->generate_filename('js'); 
                $output_js = $this->get_js_html($cachefile_js); 
                $cachefile_css = $this->generate_filename('css'); 
                $output_css = $this->get_css_html($cachefile_css); 
                return $output_css."\n".$cachefile_js; 
        } 
    } 

    private function generate_filename($type) { 
        $this->libs[$type] = array_unique($this->libs[$type]); 

        // Create cache folder if not exist 
        if(!file_exists($this->cachePath[$type])) { 
            mkdir($this->cachePath[$type]); 
        } 

        // Define last modified to refresh cache if needed 
        $lastmodified = 0; 
        foreach($this->libs[$type] as $key => $lib) { 
            $lib = $this->clean_lib_list($lib, $type); 
            if(file_exists($this->basePath[$type].'/'.$lib)) { 
                $lastmodified = max($lastmodified, filemtime($this->basePath[$type].'/'.$lib)); 
            } 
            $this->libs[$type][$key] = $lib; 
        } 
        $hash = $lastmodified.'-'.md5(serialize($this->libs[$type]).'_'.serialize($this->inline_code[$type])); 
        return 'cache-'.$hash.'.'.$type; 
    } 

    private function get_js_html($cachefile) { 
        if(file_exists($this->cachePath['js'].'/'.$cachefile)) { 
            return '<script src="'.'/'.$this->__options['js']['cachePath'].'/'.$cachefile.'" type="text/javascript"></script>'; 
        } 
        // Get the content 
        $file_content = ''; 
        foreach($this->libs['js'] as $lib) { 
            $file_content .= "\n\n".file_get_contents($this->basePath['js'].'/'.$lib); 
        } 

        // If compression is enable, compress it ! 
        if($this->__options['js']['enableCompression']) { 
            App::import('Vendor', 'jsmin/jsmin'); 
            $file_content = trim(JSMin::minify($file_content)); 
        } 

        // Get inline code if exist 
        // Do it after jsmin to preserve variable's names 
        if(!empty($this->inline_code['js'])) { 
            foreach($this->inline_code['js'] as $inlineJs) { 
                $file_content .= "\n\n".$inlineJs; 
            } 
        } 

        if($fp = fopen($this->cachePath['js'].'/'.$cachefile, 'wb')) { 
            fwrite($fp, $file_content); 
            fclose($fp); 
        } 
        return '<script src="'.'/'.$this->__options['js']['cachePath'].'/'.$cachefile.'" type="text/javascript"></script>'; 
    } 

    private function get_css_html($cachefile) { 
        if(file_exists($this->cachePath['css'].'/'.$cachefile)) { 
            return '<link href="'.'/'.$this->__options['css']['cachePath'].'/'.$cachefile.'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >'; 
        } 
        // Get the content 
        $file_content = ''; 
        foreach($this->libs['css'] as $lib) { 
            $file_content .= "\n\n".file_get_contents($this->basePath['css'].'/'.$lib); 
        } 

        // Get inline code if exist 
        if(!empty($this->inline_code['css'])) { 
            foreach($this->inline_code['css'] as $inlineCss) { 
                $file_content .= "\n\n".$inlineCss; 
            } 
        } 

        // If compression is enable, compress it ! 
        if($this->__options['css']['enableCompression']) { 
            App::import('Vendor', 'csstidy', array('file' => 'class.csstidy.php')); 
            $tidy = new csstidy(); 
            $tidy->load_template($this->__options['css']['compression']); 
            $tidy->set_cfg('sort_selectors', FALSE); 
            $tidy->set_cfg('sort_properties', FALSE); 
            $tidy->parse($file_content); 
            $file_content = $tidy->print->plain(); 
        } 

        if($fp = fopen($this->cachePath['css'].'/'.$cachefile, 'wb')) { 
            fwrite($fp, $file_content); 
            fclose($fp); 
        } 
        return '<link href="'.'/'.$this->__options['css']['cachePath'].'/'.$cachefile.'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >'; 
    } 

    function add_libs($type, $libs) { 
        switch($type) { 
            case 'js': 
            case 'css': 
                if(is_array($libs)) { 
                    foreach($libs as $lib) { 
                        $this->libs[$type][] = $lib; 
                    } 
                }else { 
                    $this->libs[$type][] = $libs; 
                } 
                break; 
        } 
    } 

    function add_inline_code($type, $codes) { 
        switch($type) { 
            case 'js': 
            case 'css': 
                if(is_array($codes)) { 
                    foreach($codes as $code) { 
                        $this->inline_code[$type][] = $code; 
                    } 
                }else { 
                    $this->inline_code[$type][] = $codes; 
                } 
                break; 
        } 
    } 

    private function clean_lib_list($filename, $type) { 
        if (strpos($filename, '?') === false) { 
            if (strpos($filename, '.'.$type) === false) { 
                $filename .= '.'.$type; 
            } 
        } 

        return $filename; 
    } 

    private function clean_path($path) { 
        // delete the / at the end of the path 
        $len = strlen($path); 
        if(strrpos($path, '/') == ($len - 1)) { 
            $path = substr($path, 0, $len - 1); 
        } 

        // delete the / at the start of the path 
        if(strpos($path, '/') == '0') { 
            $path = substr($path, 1, $len); 
        } 
        return $path; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<?php $combinator->add_libs('js', array('jquery', 'other_lib', 'third_lib'));?>
```

By the way, if you are implementing the Combinator plugin right now in your app, I suggest you to use Mark Story's [AssetCompress Plugin](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress) which is more up to date and well documented.